# How to set TextField at the top of the position?

Tags: java, javafx

HiEveryone,

I'm new in `JavaFx` and my `TextField` shows at the middle of the frame but not at the top's position. Where am i suppose to be wrong? pls help..

Have a look into this screenshot..

[image]

But i want to set that TextField at the top ..

Here is Source code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.setTitle("Modern web browser.");
        WebView wv = new WebView();
        WebEngine we = wv.getEngine();
        we.load("http://www.google.com/");

        TextField tf = new TextField("http://www.google.com/");
        tf.setMaxHeight(Double.MIN_VALUE);
        GridPane sp = new GridPane();
        sp.getChildren().add(wv);
        sp.getChildren().add(tf);

        Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 600, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Please help.. Thanks in Advanced!

**EDITED**

As @Nagesh Kumar answered me after using `VBox` getting this error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your layout to VBox from GridPane as follows

```
VBox vbox = new VBox();
```

Now first add your TextField first so that it will be on top as follows

```
vbox.getChildren().add(tf);
```

then a WebView as follows

```
vbox.getChildren().add(wv);
```

Edit:
Yes you can try this

```
VBox vbox = new VBox(5);
```

5 pixel space between controls put in VBox

Comment: Okay w8 pls.. I'm trying this

Comment: One more thing would like to ask .. can we give space in between .. see blue line in this [SCREENSHOT](http://postimg.org/image/wbl9ofvxf/)